# How can I save my dying cat palm?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, indoors, palm

I bought my cat palm in July and it lived outside until the weather turned cold. It’s been indoors for a couple of months now and I fear that I over watered it once and it caused multiple leaves to turn black and so I trimmed them off. Now my cat palm looks like it’s going through a slow and painful death.

I also found white chalky stuff on the stems and sprayed it with Apple Cider Vinegar to kill whatever was infesting my palm. It’s still the middle of winter where I am and I’m contemplating whether or not I should report the cat palm now or hope that it survives until Spring to repot and put it back outside where natural environment can hopefully bring it back to life.

Picture 1. Cat Palm in October looking Healthy and Full
Picture 2: Cat Palm in January looking deadly
Picture 3 & 4 are the best shots I could take of the white spots I found on the stems
Pictures 5 & 6 are the leaves turning black

[image: This is a picture of my Cat Palm in October looking healthy and full][image: Cat Palm in January looking like it's dying][image: White spots b4][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Please add a closeup photo of the underside of a leaf or where the white stuff was

Comment: Please don't shrink the photos that you upload, because such tiny pics will not relay any meaningful information about the state of the plant. Also without uploading any additional detailed pics nobody's gonna be able to help you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it’s root bound. Small pot for the size of plant and those put out new root shoots all the time.